# is "xxx-japanese" a good tag convention?

Tags: discussion, tags

We had voted earlier to remove "Japanese" as a tag from this site.  I would conclude that this also means removal as a suffix as sorts as well.

There is currently "internet-Japanese" and "business-Japanese".  Both could be changed to "xxx-lingo" to get rid of the Japanese, but I still think that a single worded tag is best in these scenarios.

Comment: Don't forget corporate-Japanese, which should probably be merged with business-Japanese.

Comment: @Troyen: There was only [one question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83/at-work-when-is-it-not-ok-to-finish-an-email-with) with that tag, and it seems that the [corporate-japanese] tag was created without knowing the existence of the [business-japanese] there, so I [boldly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold) removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree that a single-word tag would be a good replacement.  [internet-japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-japanese) and [business-japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-japanese) mean the *language* used in a specific context.  I don't think just plain "business" or "internet" convey that meaning.

I agree that "xxx-japanese" is not a great tag convention, but nothing I can think of (-lingo, -language) sounds as good or has the same meaning.